# Not scraping correct values despite it being correct in chrome inspect

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape data off the site below however it seems I can't seem to find a css selector where it will display a correct output.

For this [website](https://www.bookmaker.com.au/sports/soccer/41044779-football-australia-australian-a-league/), I have tried: `.row:nth-child(1) span` as well as other css selectors.

I am yet to find a working xpath as it is not like Nth-childs to try to see if it makes any difference

[image]

I've posted my full code [here](https://pastebin.com/cdFcF58L)

Comment: Which value do you want to scrape?

Comment: @DebanjanB All the values highlighted green/under the win tab (win odds) https://ibb.co/nQMOyG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below XPath should return you desired output:

```
//tr[starts-with(@id, "twirl_element_")][1]/td[@class="win odds"]//span
```

Comment: Hadn't thought to use starts-with/contains.  Thank you.